# How do I kill one cron job before executing another one?

Tags: linux, cron, kill

In the `crontab -u pi -e` of my digital picture frame I have got two processes.

The first one calls [`feh`](http://feh.finalrewind.org) on reboot and starts a slide show.

```
@reboot bash /home/pi/ledslide1.sh >> /home/pi/logs/slidelog 2&>1
```

And then other instances should be started at certain times.

```
15 8 * * * bash /home/pi/ledslide2.sh >> /home/pi/logs/slidelog 2&>1
15 9 * * * bash /home/pi/ledslide3.sh >> /home/pi/logs/slidelog 2&>1
...
```

But the `feh` slide show is running on repeat. That way I have to kill the process first right? `timeout` is not working, because I don’t know when the reboot takes place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ledslide.sh scripts, just use `pkill -9 feh` to kill `feh`. No need to keep track of PIDs or anything. `pkill` is used to search for and kill processes with a given name. I suggesting reading the `manpage` for `pkill` and `pgrep`.

Comment: I did put this command in the crontab. But it is more or less the same?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me so far:

```
@reboot bash /home/pi/ledslide1.sh >> /home/pi/logs/slidelog 2&>1
15 8 * * * pkill -9 feh && bash /home/pi/ledslide2.sh >> /home/pi/logs/slidelog 2&>1
```

The .sh file invokes `feh` and puts it into the background. `pkill -9 [KEYWORD]` closes the `feh` process.